# Use of templates in function parameters and return type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a struct with a template in function parameters and return type while declaring function.

```
template <typename T>
struct my_struct { 
  T value; 
}; 

my_struct<T> func(my_struct<T> input_1, my_struct<T> input_2);
```

When I tried the above code I'm getting

> error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope

However, when declaring with concrete data_type, it compiles.

```
my_struct<float> func(my_struct<float> input_1, my_struct<float> input_2);
```

Does it mean, I've to declare function for all data types that I expect? Clearly, I misunderstood the concept here. Can someone explain this?

Comment: For question2, `X` is not deducible, so call `func<float>(t1, t2);`.

Comment: One question by question, you might have asked another question instead of editing that question to include extra question.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You can still access waht you have written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68315662/revisions) and copy it to a new quesiton. Though as Jarod42 said, you either need to specify the template parameters or they must be deducible from function paramters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `func` as template if you want it to be a template. `T` is only declared inside the definition of the template `my_struct`.

```
template <typename T>
my_struct<T> func(my_struct<T> input_1, my_struct<T> input_2);
```

Or if you actually want no template, but an instantiation of `my_struct`, eg for `int`

```
my_struct<int> func(my_struct<int> input_1, my_struct<int> input_2);
```

Comment: Thanks, till now I was under the assumption the scope of template <typename T> is the whole file.

Comment: I've updated the question. can you please answer the question2? Thanks.

Comment: @harry please do not change the quesiton to ask for something else after you got answers. I mean you already accepted it, but now you changed your question such that this answer does not answer your question anymore. You can always open new questions. Altering the question to invalidate answers isnt nice. Anyhow there should be one question per quesiton

Comment: oh sorry, will create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the function template too:

```
template <typename T>
my_struct<T> func(my_struct<T> input_1, my_struct<T> input_2)
{
    // ...
}
```